# Are the elements in this “quit smoking” design easily recognisable?

Tags: logo, typography, illustration, critique

Concept:

- ban icon
- Q
- cigarette
- a copy to give a hint about cigarette

Now, the Q is visible to me, but I'm not sure about the Q and cigarette. Are ban icons and cigarettes perceivable, when talking about users who are non designers?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer a more active concept, and one in which the line of action follows the more-typical international graphic language in which the downwards portion of the cigarette is the burning end - makes clear the intended action - stopping.

More over, your smoke lines are a bit too happily-jauntily-ongoing - doesn't look like stopping smoking - the position and smoke in yours connote *talking* about quitting, but in fact *actively still* ***smoking*** as the only way a cigarette is lit, and up-angled like that is *in someone's hand* who ***is*** in fact, smoking.

I say: invert that paradigm; stub it out.

Like so.

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: I got this answer a little late, I've already shared it on social media now. But would surely update and post it next year.

Comment: The filter at the top of the stroke works well to identify the villain. I think (opinion) you could lose the smoke entirely and/or show the cigarette broken.

Answer (score 0):

The Q is certainly easily seen, especially with the association to the other letters. In short order, the cigarette is also quite clear. This is due to the implied smoke from the tip, but also due to the associated "filter" of the cigarette outside the circle. The ban icon is nearly universal and also easily perceived, perhaps from its simplicity of structure. I'm not a designer, nor do I play one on television.